# eclipse 2020-06 syntax highlighting not working with inline javascript in php or html file

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse

I had an old version of eclipse - probably 2018-12 - and all was good. Then I upgraded it because it was showing errors for some new syntax.

Now, javascript syntax highlighting and other associated things like automatic indent, brackets assistance etc are working with .js files, but when I write any javascript inside a php or html file using script tags, the code is simply black text.

I read the other questions about this issue, but they are all about it not working at all. It works for me, but only in .js files.

I did try uninstalling wild web developer and installing JSDT from 2020-03, but it was no help. Then I upgraded the JSDT to latest version - still not working. Finally I uninstalled eclipse completely and reinstalled the eclipse for PHP package. It has wild web developer by default. Still the same behaviour.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the new "Eclipse Web JavaScript Developer Tools" feature (and the related one for JSPs if you need it) from the 2020-09 prerelease site, https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-09/. They were included in the 2020-06 Enterprise Java package, but not completely set up for installing later using the 2020-06 update site. 2020-06 also lost the support for task tags in JavaScript files as Wild Web Developer doesn't support them; it'll be back in the final 2020-09 release.

[image: The Eclipse Web JavaScript Developer Tools and related feature for JSPs]